# Return results for all days of the month even if there is no data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, recursive-query

I have a select that returns a data set by DATA.
Example:
[image]

As you can see in the image below, there is no data for the days: `20,21,22 ... 28`

I would like to bring these lines with result `NULL`

My select is simple, the date column has a date PER day

```
SELECT * 
from rentabilidade_fundos 
where data BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-31' 
order by data
```

**How I needed the select to return:**
[image]

Comment: outer join a calendar help table/cte.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can generate the list of dates with a recursive query, then `left join` it with your table:

```
with calendar as (
    select '2020-04-01' dt
    union all select dt + interval 1 day where dt < '2020-04-31' from calendar
)
select c.dt, t.fundo_conservador, t.fundo_moderado, t.fundo_arrojado
from calendar c
left join mytable t on t.data = c.dt
```

You may also create a calendar table to store your dates instead of generating it on the fly, and intialize it manually, like:

```
create table calendar(dt date primary key);
insert into calendar values ('2020-04-01')? ('2020-04-02'), ...;
```

You can then use it instead of the derived table generated by the recursive cte:

```
select c.dt, t.fundo_conservador, t.fundo_moderado, t.fundo_arrojado
from calendar c
left join mytable t on t.data = c.dt
where c.dt >= '2020-04-01' and c.dt < '2020-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to generate all dates with in the time period you need. Then after you can `join` the table from which you need to query. Here is my solution.

Trying to replicate your table and its values.

```sql
INSERT INTO rentabilidade_fundos (data, conservado, moderado, arrojado)
VALUES
    ('2020-04-01', 1, 1, 1),
    ('2020-04-02', 2, 2, 2),
    ('2020-04-03', 3, 3, 3),
    ('2020-04-15', 15, 15, 15),
    ('2020-04-21', 21, 21, 21),
    ('2020-04-25', 25, 25, 25),
    ('2020-04-29', 29, 29, 29),
    ('2020-04-30', 30, 30, 30);
```

My data in the table looks like this.
[rentabilidade_fundos table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhwAB.png).

To extract all fields for the past 30 days with starting date of `2020-04-01` you can use the query below.

```sql
set @i = -1;
set @stop = 29;

SELECT rf.id, x.date, rf.conservado, rf.moderado, rf.arrojado
FROM rentabilidade_fundos rf
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT DATE(ADDDATE('2020-04-01', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS date FROM rentabilidade_fundos
    HAVING @i < @stop
) x ON x.date = rf.data
ORDER BY x.date;
```

The final result will be as below.
[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S67Zm.png)